# how to select the best dataset for training a model

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-science, sampling, training-data

I want to create a best training sample from a given set of data points by way of running all possible combinations of train and test through a model and select based on the best R2.
I do not want to run the model with all possible combinations rather I want to select like a stratified set each time and run the model. Is there a way to do this  in R.

sample dataset

```
df1 <- data.frame(
    cbind(sno=1:30 
        ,x1=c(14.3,14.8,14.8,15,15.1,15.1,15.4,15.4,16.1,14.3,14.8,14.8,15.2,15.1,15.1,15.4,15.4,16.1,14.2,14.8,14.7,15.1,15,15,15.3,15.3,15.9,15.1,15,15.3)
        ,y1=c(79.2,78.7,79,78.2,78.7,79.1,78.4,78.7,78.1,79.2,78.7,79,78.2,78.6,79.2,78.4,78.7,78.1,79.1,78.5,78.9,78,78.5,79,78.2,78.5,78,79.2,78.7,78.7)
        ,z1=c(219.8,221.6,232.5,213.1,231,247.6,230.2,240.9,245.5,122.8,124.2,131.5,119.1,130.5,141.1,130.8,137.7,140.8,25.4,30.5,30.5,23.8,29.6,34.6,29.5,33.3,35.2,105,170.7,117.3)
    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

This defeats the purpose of training.  Ideally, you have one or more training datasets and an untouched testing data set you'll ultimately test against once your model is fit.  Cherry-picking a training dataset, using R-squared or any other metric for that matter, will introduce bias.  Worse still, if your model parameters are wildly different depending on which training set you use, your model likely isn't very good and results against your testing dataset are likely to be spurious.